# Access field value in template_preprocess_views_view_field function?

Tags: views, theming

I have a client with a Drupal 8 site who prefers curly quotes to straight quotes. I have successfully made this change for node titles using a regex replacement in template_preprocess_page_title. Now I am trying to accomplish the same thing for a different text field that is rendered by a view, using template_preprocess_views_view_field or template_preprocess_views_view_fields, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get individual field values using this function. Am I even trying the correct preprocess functions?

I have also tried rewriting the output of the field by accessing the variable in a custom twig template, with poor results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends how you have your view set up.

If you have your view using the format 'Fields' then you can override the content with template_preprocess_views_view_field() like you say, like this (although you might want to target individual fields with some if statements):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for views-view-field.html.twig.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];

  if ($view->id() == 'VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    if ($field->field == 'FIELD_NAME') {
      // Replace characters in the field output.
      $variables['output'] = Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create(str_replace('find', 'replace', $variables['output']));
    }
  }
}
```

If you are using the format 'Content' then you could do it at the field template level or node template level instead, since in that case it doesn't use the views field templates.

Comment: This is really helpful. I am using the 'Fields' format in my view. Applying the replacement across the board breaks the view, so I do need to target an individual field. I'm having trouble seeing how to do this in the preprocess function, though. It was easy in Drupal 7. My field name is field_home_page_headline. Can you assist?

Comment: @JOakland I updated the example with some checks for views name & display and the field name.

Comment: That did it! Thank you for taking the time to help me resolve this. I've been banging my head against the D8 documentation for days.

Comment: @rooby
How can i use the updated field value in view custom field ?

Comment: @RajGhai what do you mean by view custom field?

Comment: @rooby for ex: i have modified the title field value using above code and i want to use the title field replacement pattern in views custom text field. i have updated title field value using your solution and its working like charm but when i use the title field pattern in  Rewrite Result of some other field then its not working.

Comment: @RajGhai rewrite field will not work because the code above is modifying the value after it has been used for rewriting. There are a number of ways you can customise views and different solutions will be preferable for different requirements. Probably best to post a new question for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You saved my life, thx so much!!